# Sublime Text 3 Vintage mode disable u for switching to lower case

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

`u` undos except if you have something selected. Then it turns selection into lower case.

Is there any way to turn of "to lower case" and have `u` doing undo no matter if you've selected some text or not?

Comment: is this a vim question or sublimetext question? also just curious, why people use some text editor but in a VI-like model to simulate vim,  instead of using vim?

Comment: Sorry Kent, maybe this is a pure sublime question. I'll remove the vim tag (if I can). I've tried to move over to vim 2 times but I did not like buffers instead of tabs and project searching + some other stuff did not behave as I wanted. I'm sure an experienced vim-user knows how to make it work as desired but I just find that I have to spend too much time to get up and running with stuff that just works "as I expect" in sublime.

Comment: vim has tab too.. anyway, good luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a Key Binding to "Key Bindings - User" for the desired key combination that will supersede the default.

On OS X I would go to:
Sublime Text
...Preferences
......Key Bindings - User

On Windows/linux (thanks @MattDMo)
Preferences
...Key Bindings - User

Then I'd add in a new key binding specific to what I want it to do.

If I want to change <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> from open a file to undo I would add

```
{ "keys": ["command+o"], "command": "undo" }
```

With that <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> would now undo for me.

More details here: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html

Comment: So simple! I ended up with `{ "keys": ["u"], "command": "undo" }` which seems to accomplish exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The menu option is `Preferences -> Key Bindings-User` on Windows and Linux. Unlike OS X, they have their own `Preferences` menu.

Comment: I had to add the context also: `{ "keys": ["u"], "command": "undo", "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}] }`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit your key bindings to do this. however if you want to turn off vintage altogether, then,

1. Select the Preferences/Settings - Default menu item
2. Edit the ignored_packages setting, change it to:

   "ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]

There is a guide to remapping keybindings [here](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/sublime/how-to-remap-escape-in-sublime-text-3s-vintage-mode)

here is an example

```
   [
        { "keys": ["j", "j"], "command": "exit_insert_mode",
            "context":
            [
                { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
                { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
            ]
        }
    ]
```